# How to Delay a For loop to cycle through an array that replaces text

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to replace this text and have the replaced text slowly loop through the array one element at a time. I did do a For loop at one point without any precautions of setting a delay and it just skipped to the end. I did find some other posts that go over loops with delays but never about replacing text fields. Right now it only shows the text "I only like Sample 2"

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var hobbies = ["Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3"];


    function myFunction()
    {
        log();
    };
       var i = 0;
function log(){
 

    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function timer() {
     var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var string = hobbies[i];
    var res = str.replace("___", string);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
  }, i * 3000);
}
    
}



</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo">
<p> I only like ___ </p>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically what you've got is working, the loop is executing 9 times.  The main problem is that `str.replace("___", string);` will only ever work once, because you are overwriting what's inside the element.

There are a few things you can do here to improve/modernise the code and fix the issue - you are very close with what you had though.

```
var hobbies = ["Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3"];

function log(){
  const elem = document.getElementById("demo");
  const startStr = "I only like";

  hobbies.forEach((hobby,i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      elem.innerHTML = `<p>${startStr} ${hobby}</p>`
    }, i * 3000);
  })
}
```

*Grab the demo element outside of your loop, that way you're not querying your DOM every time the loop runs.

*Declare your starting string so you're not having to mess around with string replace. (This can also be written where ${startStr} is instead as it is a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).

*You seem to have a function that does nothing but call another function, so your click event could simply call the latter function of log().

*You could use a forEach rather than a regular foo loop, this means you do not have to care about how many items are in your hobbies array, the forEach will happily go through them all.

Edit: To have this continually loop it would be something like this:

```
var hobbies = ["Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3"];

function loop(delayTime) {
  const elem = document.getElementById("demo");
  const startStr = "I only like";
  hobbies.forEach((hobby,i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      elem.innerHTML = `<p>${startStr} ${hobby}</p>`
    }, i * delayTime);
  })
}

function log(){
  const delayTime = 3000;
  loop(delayTime)
  setInterval(function() {
    loop(delayTime)
  }, hobbies.length * delayTime);
}
```

Comment: I added in the script you said and made my button call log() so now it looks like this: <DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script>
  var hobbies = ["Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3"];

const elem = document.getElementById("demo");
const startStr = "I only like";

function log(){
  hobbies.forEach((hobby,i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      elem.innerHTML = `<p>${startStr} ${hobby}</p>`
    }, i * 3000);
  })
}



</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="demo">
<p> I only like ___ </p>
</div>
<button onclick="log()">Click</button>

</body>
</html>

Comment: got the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at Hi.html:13 when i added it with line 13 being  elem.innerHTML = `<p>${startStr} ${hobby}</p>`

Comment: I can't replicate that exact issue.  Try moving the elem and startStr inside the function (but outside the forEach).

Comment: It's also worth noting that script tags should be placed at the end of your code just before the closing <body> tag.  The problem could simply be that your script is running before the HTML has rendered.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: How should I go about making it constantly cycle? just call the function again?

Comment: Updated to include that, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code ended up working for me, thanks for the help!

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
      var hobbies = ["Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3"];



function log(){
    const elem = document.getElementById("demo");
const startStr = "I only like";
  hobbies.forEach((hobby,i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      elem.innerHTML = `<p>${startStr} ${hobby}</p>`
    }, i * 3000);
  })
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo">
<p> I only like ___ </p>
</div>
<button onclick="log()">Click</button>

</body>
</html>
```